# Python: How do I call a script in a parent directory's subdirectory?

Tags: python, path, filesystems, directory-structure

I'm trying to open a Python script from the Python command line.  There's a bug in Python that makes adding Python to my environmental variable's path ineffective.  So, I have to run Python command line from the Python directory.

My script is at c:/mydir/myfile.py

How do I open it from c:/python27/python.exe; `>>`?

Comment: Thre is no "bug" in python regarding that. Can't say the same about your OS, though.

Comment: jsbueno, There are a lot of unreported bugs in many softwares.  Sometimes odd OS configurations cause them.  I can set my OS such that python will act irregularly, but the settings aren't unnatural to people like me.  It's equally the OS's fault for not accounting for programmers as it is the software developer's fault for not accounting for all testable behaviors.  In this case, it was neither.  It was a user error (my fault).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

access your parent directory by

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
```

then you access a subdirectory by placing a **__init__.py** in subdirectory and  writing something in it like

```
__all__ = ['myfile']
```

then you can `import myfile`

Or you just want to run it. In that case you can use an absolute path.  eg. `python c:\mydir\myfile.py`

Comment: I guess it might work.  Not sure.  Couldn't understand what you were saying.  The issue resolved itself.  I had to restart the computer or cmd prompt or something.